# Need to displace serial port across machines Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, redirection, serial

I have an app running on Linux (Ubuntu) that wants hardware attached to a serial port.

I want that hardware on a Windows machine (XP SP3) elsewhere on my LAN.

So, I need a serial port server on the Windows box to take Com1 and connect to TCP/IP. Then, a client on the Linux box to attach TCP/IP to a /dev/tty2 port.

Since these are across platforms, I think the re-directors should be RFC 2217 compliant. But I guess a non compliant single manufacturer solution that can be installed on both platforms may work.

However, it must be freeware.

I am aware of 'ser2net' on Ubuntu, and I am trying to get my mind around that.

Thanks for your help,
Mark.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have it.

On the Linux box, I installed and used the command *socat*, thus:

```
sudo socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttys1,raw,echo=0,waitslave tcp:192.168.1.95:3000;
```

(note the lower case s in ttys. This seems to be allowed in my app.) 
This created a link called /dev/ttys1 that points to /dev/pts/1.

Then on Windows, I am using *piracom* here [Pira CZ Remote COM Port | Pira.cz](http://www.pira.cz/show.asp?art=piracom).

I set this to use Com1 (where my hardware is located), and the same port as above (3000.)

I am working on permissions now. Both my app, and socat complain if I don't put 
**sudo** in front, but I think I can handle that.

It only remains to be seen how reliable this will be. If piracom or socat disconnect, it would be nice to have an automated script to detect and to fix them.

Mark.